# define named range in Excel 2003 INDIRECTLY referencing another workbook

Tags: excel, validation

I am trying to define a named range in a particular workbook in Excel 2003. Specifically, I want to assign the name "Name" to a range (list of data) on, let's say, Sheet 4 of workbook "Hours". This list of data is itself an output of formulas referencing another workbook ("Task Break-Down"). For example, cell A2 of Sheet 4 ("Hours" workbook) ='[Task Break-Down.xls]Sheet2'!A2&"".

When I create/define the named range as described above, it will show up in the list of named ranges when clicking ctrl F3. However, when I reference the named range in a formula (using "Name"), it doesn't work. Also, when I click the little drop down arrow next to the name box in the top left corner to display named ranges, "Name" does not show up. Any idea why?

I am trying to use the range "Name" (again, consisting of outputs of formulas referencing another workbook) as a reference within a formula that specifies the "source" in data validation.

The range "Name" is defined as follows:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet4!$B$1,1,0,SUMPRODUCT((Sheet4!$B:$B<>""+0)-1,1)
```

It is meant to be dynamic range (thus OFFSET...).

The data validation source is as follows:

```
=OFFSET(OFFSET(Name,0,1,1,1),Match(E2,Name,0)-1,0,COUNTIF(Name,E3))
```

Interestingly, the reference "Name" and data validation drop down (as defined above) work perfectly when opening in excel 2007+ in compatibility mode (.xls).

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: yes, it does. I think it has to do with the SUMPRODUCT part of the formula defining the range "Name" (particularly the special characters <>"", most likely). I'm saying this because I tried replacing the SUMPRODUCT part with COUNTA(Shet4!$B:$B)-1 and it works. However, the problem with that is that the range will include cells that contain formulas in them who's output result in nothing (cells look empty...similar to =""), which is not what I want. I want to exclude empty-looking cells from the named range.

Comment: Is there another way to specify that the range should include only cells actually showing a value, besides the sumproduct function with special characters above?

Comment: again, it's interesting that the whole thing (with SUMPRODUCT) works great in Excel 2007 and up.